# java bytecode:two for-loop on onmethodExit

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

i have a test method:

```
public List<User> getUsers(){
List list = new ArrayList();
return list;
}
```

so,I want insert two for-loop code to the method, to new list before and after, asm code same is :

```
final int returnValueStackNum = adapter.newLocal(Type.INT_TYPE);
mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_0);
mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ISTORE, returnValueStackNum);
final Label l0 = new Label();
mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, l0);
final Label l1 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l1);
mv.visitIincInsn(returnValueStackNum, 1);
mv.visitLabel(l0);
mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ILOAD, returnValueStackNum);
mv.visitIntInsn(Opcodes.BIPUSH, 10);
mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.IF_ICMPLT, l1);
```

first for-loop is right in new class file, but second for-loop is wrong and return is lost, code same:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
int j = 0;
tmpTernaryOp = localArrayList;
while (j < 10)
   j++;
```

Where has the problem, thank you very much

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);  whats the use of this(notice the semi colon in the end) ?..It ended right on the same line..

Comment: yes, for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++); has no code, is a empty for-loop, two for-loop is same, but second empty have a error, the returnValue assigned to a strange variable,Note, the ASM code in the onmethodExit method

Answer (score 0):

In the topic you mention onmethodexit which leads me to guess you are using AdviceAdapter to add code to the end of methods. This is a good. I assume the code you showed was copypasted from the onMethodExit() method.

However in your code you seem to be using both `adapter` and `mv` variables - what does the "adapter" variable contain? My guess is you should not need the adapter variable at all - instead call newLocal() directly in the onMethodExit() method.

If you are using some separate adapter which is not chained properly it will probably "allocate" variables that are already in use.

So without more code to understand the whole picture, my suggestion is: try changing `adapter.newLocal(Type.INT_TYPE)` to just `newLocal(Type.INT_TYPE)`.